# What happened to randomkit.h or how to migrate to the latest numpy.random c/cython api

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a cython extension module that uses a small subset of numpy.random. It works fine in 16.2

Now, apparently there has just been a major reorg of the numpy random module https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/d8e145743813545b11be1f588f4fedb88addf059#diff-51bde9aa0f8211110b1c0aabe79fec5b

While these changes are gentle on the python user, they completely break my cython code.

As far as I can tell, from 17.0 on:

1. The header `randomkit.h` is gone.
2. `rk_*` symbols are gone. (They used to be in `mtrand.cpython-<platform>.so`).

Questions:

1. Is my interpretation of the situation correct?
2. Any help with migrating (Pointers, suggestions)?

Here is a snippet of my code showing the old api and what little of it I'm using:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "randomkit.h":
    ctypedef struct rk_state:
        unsigned long key[624]
        < snip >
        double p4

    void rk_seed(unsigned long seed, rk_state *state)
    unsigned long RK_MAX
    unsigned long rk_interval(unsigned long max, rk_state *state)
    unsigned long rk_random(rk_state *state)
```

Comment: It looks as if numpy no longer uses rk_random, as it uses MT19937 (and what not) instead. So it is no longer built (here is the commit that removed the the old version from setup.py: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/4e6a812732b4c09b20354a47d488fbe384124827#diff-2f11e10eaeaf898365b33a912c05d104). Your options are probably either to switch the the new generators or to build randomkit as a part of your package.

Comment: FWIW: I've opened a github issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14517

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randomkit.h` and the interfaces it contained have indeed been [retired](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14517) to make room for a new infrastructure. Whether the new api will be stable/officially supported is unclear at the time of writing, though, the fact that it is already [documented](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/extending.html#cython) in [some detail](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/v1.17.2/numpy/random/examples) does suggest so.